# Can't attach document to gmail in kotlin ( itextpdf )

Tags: android, kotlin, itext

I am trying to attach a document generated using itextpdf to gmail ( using intents ) . It worked for other applications ( whatsapp, telegram etc ) ,but the email gives the error "can't attach to email"

```
val mDoc = Document()
val mFileName = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(System.currentTimeMillis())

val mFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + mFileName + ".pdf"
val database = AppDatabase.getInstance(context = this)
/// Test
try {

    PdfWriter.getInstance(mDoc, FileOutputStream(mFilePath))

    mDoc.open()

    /// stuff 

}


mDoc.close()

val mUri = Uri.parse(mFilePath)
val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
emailIntent.type = "vnd.android.cursor.dir/email"
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, mUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Trimite Emailul"));
```

Comment: is there a stacktrace you can get from adb?

Comment: No. There is nothing abnormal